# Should onHandleIntent be called when IntentService is started with bindService?

Tags: android, intentservice

My service extends `IntentService` and when it is started with `startService`, `onHandleIntent` gets called. However, when the service is started with `bindService` (I do need binding), `onHandleIntent` does not get called.

Should `onHandleIntent` be called when `IntentService` is started with `bindService`? Is `startService` the only way `IntentService` should be started?

The documentation for `IntentService` says the following:

***Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls;** the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.*

Currently I solve my problem by calling `startService` right after `bindService` but I find it ugly. I would like to know is there a way to make it work with just one call.

Code snippets follow, it might be that I am missing something obvious.

**ExampleService.java**

```
public class ExampleService extends IntentService {

private class IncomingHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {

        if (message.replyTo != null) {
            outMessenger = message.replyTo;
        }
    }
}

private Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler()); 
private Messenger outMessenger = null;


public ExampleService() {
    super("ExampleService");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return messenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

    System.out.println("Service started");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        SystemClock.sleep(5000);

        if (outMessenger != null) {
            try {
                outMessenger.send(Message.obtain());
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Service Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.service"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".ExampleService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.service.ExampleService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java** (caller)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection {


private class IncomingHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("Message received!");
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}

private Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.service.ExampleService");
            bindService(intent, MainActivity.this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            //startService(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {

    Message message = Message.obtain();
    message.replyTo = messenger;

    try {
        new Messenger(binder).send(message);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should onHandleIntent be called when IntentService is started with bindService?

No.

> Is startService the only way IntentService should be started?

IMHO, yes. IMHO, `IntentService` is not designed for the binding pattern.

In your case, you can:

- Pass a `Messenger` from the activity in an `Intent` extra in the command sent by `startService()`, or
- Use `LocalBroadcastManager`, or
- Use [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/), or
- Use an ordered broadcast, if the `IntentService` might continue past the activity's life and you want to, say, display a `Notification` when the work gets done in that case,
- Etc.

Comment: I ended up passing a Messenger via Intent extras. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must call both startService and bindService.
This was worked for me.