# Access TextView and Progressbar in Recyclerview from IntentService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, simpleadapter

I am having a recyclerview which has a **TextView (progresstxt) and a Progressbar (downloadprogress)** as part of the inflated items.

**I need to know how I can access the TextView and Progressbar in the SimpleAdapter from the IntentService so I can update their values?**

I am trying to achieve this with a **BroadcastReceiver** but it doesn`t work, the TextView and Progressbar are not being updated.

Thank you in advance.

I access the TextView and Progressbar through onBindViewHolder.

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> implements FollowRedirectsCallback {

private final Context mContext;
private String recievedStr;
private int receivedProg;

private MyBroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver;
private MyBroadcastReceiver_Update myBroadcastReceiver_Update;

public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView title, progresstxt;
        public ProgressBar downloadprogress;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.simple_text);
            progresstxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_text);
            downloadprogress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressdownload);
        }
    ...
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            recievedStr = intent.getStringExtra(MoService.EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE);
            //progresstxt.setText(result); ?
            //how to access the TextView in onBindViewHolder?
        }
    }

public class MyBroadcastReceiver_Update extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        receivedProg = intent.getIntExtra(MoService.EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE_PROGRESS, 0);
        //downloadprogress.setProgress(update); ?
        //how to access the Progressbar in onBindViewHolder?

    }
}

...

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      //
        myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        myBroadcastReceiver_Update = new MyBroadcastReceiver_Update();

        //register BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MoService.ACTION_MyIntentService);
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        mContext.registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        IntentFilter intentFilter_update = new IntentFilter(MoService.ACTION_MyUpdate);
        intentFilter_update.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        mContext.registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver_Update, intentFilter_update);

      //
        holder.progresstxt.setText(recievedStr);
        holder.downloadprogress.setProgress(receivedProg);
        holder.progresstxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.downloadprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      //
    }

    mContext.unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver_Update);
}
```

Through a **IntentService (MoService)** several file operations are done and I want to **access/update** the TextView and Progressbar from this IntentService.

```
public class MoService extends IntentService {

public static final String ACTION_MyIntentService = "com.sample.RESPONSE";
    public static final String ACTION_MyUpdate = "com.sample.UPDATE";
    public static final String EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE = "EXTRA_UPDATE";
    public static final String EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE_PROGRESS = "EXTRA_UPDATE_PROGRESS";
    String message;
    int mProgress;
..
public MoService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        context = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //
        Intent intentUpdate = new Intent();
        intentUpdate.setAction(ACTION_MyUpdate);
        intentUpdate.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intentUpdate.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE, message);
        sendBroadcast(intentUpdate);
    //
    }

class MyDownloadDownloadStatusListener implements DownloadStatusListener {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadComplete(DownloadRequest request) {
           message = "Status: completed...";
           mProgress = 0;
           progresstxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           downloadprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
..
  }
}
```

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498919/should-onhandleintent-be-called-when-intentservice-is-started-with-bindservice

Comment: unRegister your broadcast in receiver and delete this lines from bindViewHolder `mContext.unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver_Update);`

Comment: Thx Rajesh but this doesn`t change anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the code. You should not create a new Receiver in your onBindViewHolder method.
There should be a single receiver which updates the Item list used by your adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

Hope it helps

Comment: Can this then be done without a broadcastreceiver? I just need to access to the TextView and Progressbar but my problem is they are in a viewholder.

Comment: Broadcast receiver is the easiest way to accomplish this. TextView and progressbar are finally populated by the underlying data. So it is better to change the underlying data rather that getting the reference to the textview and progressbar and changing the values